# Query with identical query plan but different limits have vastly different execution times

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan, mysql-5.7, query-planner

I have the below table (simplified) where there are approximately 2 million records in the table, with `tickets.spam = FALSE` for the majority of records, and only 31 records with `tickets.spam = TRUE`.

```
CREATE TABLE tickets (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  account_id INT,
  w_id INT,
  spam BOOLEAN,
  due_by DATE
);
```

The below query returns data in under 200ms.

```
SET SESSION query_cache_type = OFF;
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE tickets.*
FROM tickets
WHERE tickets.account_id = 95
  AND tickets.w_id IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
  AND tickets.spam = TRUE
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0;
```

This is the query plan

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | tickets | p127 | ref | --- | index_acc_due_ws_id | 8 | const | 1049925 | 5.00 | Using index condition; Using where |

But if change the limit to 26 instead of 25 the execution time goes for 5 seconds.

```
FROM tickets
WHERE tickets.account_id = 95
  AND tickets.w_id IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
  AND tickets.spam = TRUE
LIMIT 26 OFFSET 0;
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | tickets | p127 | ref | --- | index_acc_due_ws_id | 8 | const | 1049925 | 5.00 | Using index condition; Using where |

And `index_acc_due_ws_id` is an index on `account_id`, `due_by`, `w_id`, and `id` in that order.

My understanding is when the LIMIT is greater than the available number of records it might default to a full table scan to fetch the required number of records. However, since we have 31 records I'm not sure why this happens at 26 records.

Also, how do we effectively work with columns that have a huge data skew?

Comment: Maybe the 26th result is a lot further down the list? Why not get the row numbers to see...

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly why you had such a big discontinuity in execution times without using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE FORMAT=TREE`, but that is not available in MySQL 5.7.

You do need to include your `spam` column in your multicolumn index, especially considering your `WHERE ... spam = TRUE` filter gets rid of the vast majority of your rows.  Try this.

```sql
CREATE INDEX spam_account_wid ON tickets(account_id, spam, w_id);
```

Once this index is in place, you may be able to speed things up another little bit by doing `tickets.w_id BETWEEN 2 AND 6` instead of using `IN(2,3,4,5,6)`. It does a range scan on the last column of the multi-column index.